# ASP.NET MVC Routes Rest Standards URL Parameters

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-routing, maproute

Having a bit of a nightmare, hopefully I'm just being stupid.

I have the following controller actions:

```
<HttpGet()>
Function News() As ActionResult
End Function

<HttpGet()>
Function News(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult
End Function
```

I want it to be smart, and go to the first if I have no ID in the url, and the second if there is.

I got the following error:

> The current request for action 'News' on controller type 'MarketsController' is ambiguous >between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult News() on type TradeChaseMVC.MarketsController
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult News(Int32) on type TradeChaseMVC.MarketsController

So, I thought if i explicitly created routes without the id parameter optional, like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute( _
        "Default2", _
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index"},
        New With {.action = "^[a-zA-Z_]+$", .id = "\d{1,8}|"}
    )

    routes.MapRoute( _
        "Default", _
        "{controller}/{action}",
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index"},
        New With {.action = "^[a-zA-Z_]+$"}
    )
```

It would work, but it doesn't same error.

Now I know the simple solution is to call my methods different things, but i don't want to do this.

I was also thinking of creating an attribute to prefix the ID method, to check for ID being there, and if it isn't dont allow that method, but I can't get this to work either.

Any help would be appreciated.
Karl

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this usring UrlParameter.Optional and nullable id:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
    "Default2", _
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
    New With {.action = "^[a-zA-Z_]+$", .id = "\d{1,8}|"}
)

Function News(ByVal id As Integer?) As ActionResult
    if id.HasValue then 
         ...
    else
        ...
    end if 
End Function
```

Comment: Yes I know I could do this, I just wanted to avoid it if possible

Answer (score 1):

No the problem is still that once it identifies the name of the action to be called, the MVC action invoker can't choose between the two methods because it doesn't analyse the request to see which parameters *might* be bound.

The parameter binding stage doesn't occur until the method is selected; so you are going to have to give them different names - or you could make the `id` parameter a nullable integer (and keep the optional id route parameter as default) and simply chain to the other overload if it comes in null.

If you do this, be sure to decorate the non-parameter overload with the `NonActionAttribute` so the action invoker doesn't get confused or, indeed, make it private/protected.

## Update

An update following our comments - you don't have to go back on REST standards if you rename your action method - you just make your routes more specific (I apologise in advance - VB.Net is not even my second language!):

```
<HttpGet()>
<ActionName("AllNews")>
Function News() As ActionResult 
End Function

<HttpGet()>
Function News(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult
End Function  

'-- route for single news item with constraint
routes.MapRoute(
  "News",
  "Markets/News/{id}",
  New With { .controller = "Markets", .action = "News" }, 
  New With { .id = "\d{1,8}" });

'-- route for the all news action method
routes.MapRoute(
  "AllNews",
  "Markets/News",
  New With { .controller = "Markets", .action = "AllNews" });
```

Now you have to explicit routes that target the two action methods but under the same RESTful uri scheme.

All my MVC REST services tend to use many more explicit routes like this for the exact same reason that you're trying to solve.

Comment: Hi, I've gone down the route of creating an attribute <Rest.Enforce("id", False)>, and decorating both methods one with true and one with false, the attribute will check for the specified route param.  This seems to work but its a bit pants, its a shame it can't match the request to method signatures, if anyone has a better idea i'd love to know

Comment: @Karl Stoney - to be honest if it were me then I would be using an explicit name for the action method and an explicit route - more easily readable for other MVC devs.

Comment: We're trying where possible to follow rest guidelines, our rest api will match the same naming convention but return json instead of a view

Comment: @Karl Stoney - you don't have to sacrifice URL standards if you rename the action method and use explicit routes - see my updated answer.